# Java testing: How to run custom code when instances become eligible for GC?

Tags: java, mockito, completable-future, finalizer, finalize

I want to know if there is a way to detect when a `CompletableFuture` instance becomes eligible for garbage collection before anyone ever called `.get()` on it. I want to do this detection during Java testing, where I can use any tools from PowerMockito.

---

Long explanation:

We implement asynchronous operations using methods that return `CompletableFuture`s, and those futures are completed when the operation completes. Often, an asynchronous operation will involve calling another asynchronous operation as part of its task, and then we use `.thenCompose()` on the future of that subtask and return the result, to take the result of the subtask and potentially do some more processing, and then complete the future of our main task.

Sometimes, when the result of a subtask is unused, people forget to call `.thenCompose()` or any similar methods on the future returned by a subtask; instead, they just discard the future that is returned as if it were a synchronous call. This can cause us to complete the future of the main task before the subtask is done, which may cause subtle race conditions in our code.

Now, I know that a future being discarded isn't always wrong; perhaps you want to finish your main task without waiting for the subtask to finish. Let's assume for the sake of this question that in the use cases in our code, we will always want to wait for the subtask to finish before finishing the main task. I know that it's also possible to use something like `.applyToEither()` to complete a future when either of two futures complete, and the other future is discarded; let's assume for the sake of this question that we never use that in our code.

I thought that one way to detect when a future is discarded without being used is to detect when it becomes eligible for garbage collection (i.e. there are no more active references to it in the program), without `.get()` ever having been called on it (since all the methods that use the result of the future call `.get()` on it).

I though that one way to do that might be to wrap the `.get()` method to record that the future was used, and wrap the `.finalize()` method to check that the future was used. However, I don't think `CompletableFuture` overrides `finalize()`, and I am not sure if I can wrap it anyway. And even if I could wrap `.finalize()`, lots of places say not to rely on `.finalize()`, because it is not called immediately when the object is eligible for garbage collection, but when the garbage collector determines that the object is eligible, which can be an undetermined amount of time later. So I would need to somehow force the garbage collector to fully run and call `.finalize()` on all eligible objects at the end of each test in order for this to work. Is this possible?

Alternately, do you have any other suggestions as to how to detect that a `CompletableFuture` was not used (i.e. `.get()` never called before it is destroyed).

Comment: I dont think your current approach will work, you are looking for a static property of the code and hoping to detect it at runtime, during a test. GC may not even run. In theory, These things should come up in code reviwes. But that depends a lot on your processes and development scale.

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental error in your logic. Whether the people call `get` or `thenCompose` on the future doesn’t change the way your dependent actions are completed. When there is a race condition, it is there independently of what the caller does with the future. And well, making the code rely on an even less predictable thing like garbage collection, will never fix the problem.